# How can I determin the amplitude of a stable limit cycles?

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

Given the following system dependent on the parameter $\mu$ :

\begin{equation*}
   \begin{cases}
   \dot{x}=y+(\mu-1)x-x^3 \\ \dot{y}=-x+(\mu-1)y+2x^3
   \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I was asked for which values of $\mu$ are stable limit cycles present.
I have found out that for $\mu=1$ there is a Hopf bifurcation, and according to the theory since the Lyapunov number is negative a stable limit cycle bifurcates from the origin for $\mu > 1$

Now I am asked to investigate the amplitude of the stable limit cycles as a function of $\mu$. But I have no clue how to do that and I cannot find anything about on any of my books.
Any suggestions? :)

Comment: In case of Andronov-Hopf bifurcation many books derive asymptotics of $O(\sqrt{\mu-1})$ for the amplitude of bifurcating limit cycle. I doubt that in case of your system it will be possible to find exact formula since this system can't be written in nice form $\dot{R} = f(R)$ where the answer would be obvious.

Comment: You might be expected to note the following. Scaling $x(t)=\epsilon u(t)$, $y(t)=\epsilon v(t)$ with $\epsilon^2=\mu-1$ and considering $U(t)=\begin{pmatrix}u(t)\\ v(t)\end{pmatrix}$, one gets $$U'(t)=RU(t)+\epsilon^2\begin{pmatrix}u(t)-u(t)^3\\ v(t)+2u(t)^3\end{pmatrix}$$
where $R=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is the matrix of the rotation of angle $+\frac\pi2$.
Assuming that $U(t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\epsilon^{2n}U_n(t)$ for some $U_n(t)=\begin{pmatrix}u_n(t)\\ v_n(t)\end{pmatrix}$ one sees that $U'_0(t)=RU_0(t)$, which is solved by $U_0(t)=e^{tR}U_0(0)$ ...

Comment: ... with $e^{tR}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}$. Thus, $(u_0(t),v_0(t))$ runs along circles centered at the origin, anticlockwise, at rate $1$. Assuming that the amplitude of each function $U_n$ is $O(1)$, the amplitude of $U$ is $O(1)$, that is, the amplitude of $(x,y)$ is $O(\epsilon)=O((\mu-1)^{1/2})$.